Flow is getting failed-path for the new folder is not valid
I have uploaded the below excel in sharepoint document library in order to power automate to create folder structure
Note:im only able to create 2 levels of folders dynamically and remaining subfolders were not getting created
Please note i need to create above excel details in the nested folder  into my sharepoint document library

Flow steps

Expanding Applyto each step


Expanding Apply to each step




you need to normalize your data. There are rows where the "Year" is empty, which means, the PowerAutomate try to create folders without name.
Anyway, you should put a backslash ("/") before the "Year": 
I recommend, to put the output of the action "List rows present in a table" into two different array: a year, and a month, then remove the duplicates (like

union(variables('varYear'),variables('varMonth'))

), then create the folders based these array's elements.
